# Kibana weighted average for gross profit margin

Tags: kibana, financial, weighted-average, kibana-4

I'm currently implementing Kibana 4 (v4.0.0) as a financial dashboard for our company, order data is originating from ElasticSearch. I'm struggling with the absence of a weighted average metric aggregation for calculation of the gross profit margin for a certain time interval. A possibility exists to write a custom metric, however Kibana does not show/implement custom metrics in the table visualization construction.

A small visualization of sample data:

```
**Order 1**

Revenue: 1000

Cost of goods sold: 800

Gross margin: 200

Gross margin percentage: 200 / 1000 = 0.2 (= 20%)


**Order 2**

Revenue: 100

Cost of goods sold: 20

Gross margin: 80

Gross margin percentage: 80 / 100 = 0.8 (= 80%)
```

Please refer to [this page for calculation of the gross margin percentage](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/grossmargin.asp)

I set the gross margin as a field per elasticsearch document (= order object). For example, order 1 has a 'gross_margin' field equal to 0.2. Simply returning an average of the 'gross_margin' fields ([average aggregation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html)) is not sufficient, since this would return 0.5 ((0.2 + 0.8) / 2), but the actual gross margin of the total collection is 0.254 (((1000 + 100) - (800 + 20)) / (1000 + 100)).

Perhaps this weighted average is possible with Kibana via a workaround, but I'm not able to find it in the documentation whatsoever. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide guidance. Please don't hesitate to request more information when my question is not clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar issue logged against Kibana which is currently marked as an enhancement : https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2206
You can have a look at the comments to see if anything works for you. Basically, ElasticSearch has something called scripted_metrics and when Kibana supports them, then there would be a workaround for you.